# Get last record for several items at once with mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my mongo database, I have basically 2 collections:

- pupils

  ```
  {_id: ObjectID(539ab7ffefbb93120c9697f7), firstname: 'Arnold', lastname: 'Smith'}  
  {_id: ObjectID(539ab7ffefbb93120c5473c3), firstname: 'Steven', lastname: 'Jens'}
  ```
- marks

  ```
  { date: '2014-06-12', value: 12, pupilID: 539ab7ffefbb93120c9697f7}  
  { date: '2014-06-05', value: 9, pupilID: 539ab7ffefbb93120c9697f7}  
  { date: '2014-05-10', value: 17, pupilID: 539ab7ffefbb93120c9697f7}  
  { date: '2014-05-10', value: 7, pupilID: 539ab7ffefbb93120c5473c3}
  ```

Is there a way with mongoshell to get the last mark of each pupils without having to manually loop through the list of pupils and get the last mark for each one ?

Currently I loop through each pupils and perform a:

```
db.marks.find({pupilID: pupilID}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1)
```

But I'm quite concerned regarding the performances if the marks collections contains a high number of items.

Comment: Well you could use the `$in` operator for a "list" of pupils. Maybe not all but some at least. You haven't even made it clear "how" you are currently doing this.

Comment: $in will allow to get the the list of marks but how can I get the last mark for each pupils ?

Comment: As shown below. Better than doing this per pupil. I am not assuming as may be the case for you that `_id` is actually the "last" item. But if it is then it is also valid for sorting on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your dates are not the best example here as they are strings. You should convert them to proper "Date" types, but at least they are lexical for sorting.

Not the "join" you seem to be implicitly looking for, but you can get the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) mark for each student from your "marks" collection, which will probably do some way to helping your result:

```js
db.marks.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$pupilID",
        "date": { "$last": "$date" },
        "value": { "$last": "$value" }
    }}
]}
```

And that will give you the last mark "value" by date for each "pupilID". The joining of data is up to you, but this is better than looping whole collections or otherwise firing off on query per "pupil".

Comment: "_id": "$pupilID" was not working, I had to change to "_id": { "pupilID": "$pupilID"}. When the $last on value, is there any possibility to return the whole record (not only value but also the data of the last mark) ?

Comment: @Luc I am only referring to the data that you have posted for the field names, it seems your actual data is different. You can add as many fields as you want using the same `$last` operator. Do you need a specific example?

Comment: it's working fine, thanks. Just the "_id": "$pupilID" that I had to modify